# SuiteScript 2.0 setValue not allowed in the current subrecord

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to set a value for the sublist 'addressbookaddress'. But the script fail with error. However, I'm able to get the subrecord value.

Error:

> Not supported on the current subrecord: CurrentSubrecord.setValue.

Executed code:

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.0
*@NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(["N/currentRecord"], function(currentRecord){

/*
    Copy phone number from vendor to address, when creating a new sublist entry
*/
var lineInit = function(context) { 
    var record = context.currentRecord;
    var sublistId = context.sublistId;

    var subrecord = record.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
        sublistId: sublistId,
        fieldId: 'addressbookaddress'
    });

    if (!subrecord) {
        return;
    }

    var address = subrecord.getValue({
        fieldId: 'addr1'
    });

    subrecord.setValue({
        fieldId: 'addr1',
        value: 'test'
    });

    return;
}

return {
    lineInit: lineInit,
}

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client scripts have read-only access to subrecords.

A client script can be deployed on the Address form. Using values from the `entryformquerystring` one can search for the parent record.

Comment: So it's not possible to achieve what I'm trying to do or do you have any suggestion of a workaround?

Comment: Perhaps you can achieve the same functionality with a client script attached to the address form.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to attach to the address form. I can't find it as an option in the "APPLIES TO" list.

Comment: It is possible, but it works a bit differently. Go to Customization > Forms > Address Forms, Customize/Edit the Address Form and enter the script file under Custom Code.

Comment: Cool, that actually works. But how do I then access something on the parent? Because that is were I should source the value, from the Vendor record.

Comment: One option is to get the value of the hidden field entryformquerystring and use the entityid from this value to search for the vendor and get the email address.

Comment: It seems like "entryformquerystring" isn't available on the record.

Comment: How did you try to get the field value? I tested creating a custom field and setting {entryformquerystring} as the default value (formula). That worked, so I expected getting the value by script would also work. Otherwise, can you create a field, as well?

Comment: Okay, now I understand your idea of solving this. I created the field and can access it but it seems like defaulting to {entryformquerystring} doesn't work as formula. I get the following error if I enter the string in "Default value"  and click the arrow to open formula view: "formula=ERROR: Recursive Reference&target=VALIDATION_form.defaultvalue"

Comment: Not sure why. I don't think that I opened the formula view. I just pasted the value and made sure the formula checkbox was checked.

Comment: I did exactly that now but the field ended up empty. `record.getValue({
            fieldId: 'hidden_entryformquerystring'
        });
""` Did you do anything else that could make a difference?

Comment: I would have expected the field you created to have a different ID, which starts with custrecord. Could you use that ID as fieldID? On a different note, does `record.getValue({ fieldId: 'entryformquerystring' });` return any value?

Comment: I just shortened it to make it more readable :) It is called custrecord_hidden_entryformquerystr. Making the request you mentioned with the id custrecord_hidden_entryformquerystr return an empty string ""

Comment: Oh ok. Can you temporarily display the field on the address form and see if it is populated? Is the field stored? It shouldn't be stored.

Comment: Changed Display Type to "Normal" and it is visible on the Address form. So it is created only the defaulting isn't working.

Comment: What type of field did you use? I used Free-Form Text.

Comment: So did I. Are you viewing or editing the address record when testing?

Comment: Sorry, I found the issue. I did check out the "STORE VALUE" but apparently something did go wrong. Now I did it again and the querystring work.I get the value in my script. So now I only need to define the search.